# Boost regexp - null-termination of search results

Tags: c++, boost-regex

```
  boost::regex re;
  re = "(\\d+)";
  boost::cmatch matches;
  if (boost::regex_search("hello 123 world", matches, re))
    {
    printf("Found %s\n", matches[1]); 
    }
```

Result: "Found 123 world".  I just wanted the "123".  Is this some problem with null-termination, or just misunderstanding how regex_search works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass `matches[1]` (an object of type `sub_match<T>`) to printf like that. The fact that it gives any useful result at all is something you can't count on, since printf expects a char pointer. Instead use:

```
cout << "Found " << matches[1] << endl;
```

Or if you want to use printf:

```
printf("Found %s\n", matches[1].str().c_str());
```

You can get an std::string object with the result using `matches[1].str()`.